# How to get current user in Laravel API using Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

I am using passport package for Laravel API Authentication. When I post data I get error:

> 401 Unauthorized","error":{"error":"Unauthenticated."}.

I use `Auth::user()->id;` to get current user id.

How to solve this error?

Comment: Try: `Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});`

Comment: You need to pass the Access Token in header as `Authorization: Bearer <token>` for auth protected routes. Are you doing that?

Comment: @Karthik I have posted my answer, if it helps you plz accept and upvote it!

Comment: @karthik, got your solution?

Answer (score 19):

This code helped me:

```
auth()->guard('api')->user()
```

for shortline syntax you can use something like this:

```
auth('api')->user()
```

Answer (score 7):

The simplest format is `auth('api')->user();`

Answer (score 2):

You can get current user in laravel api using passport as below:

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
 return $request->user(); 
});
```

but you are getting `401 Error` that means either you are not passing access_token in Authorization header or your access_token has expired so you have to refresh the token,

You have to pass `access_token` in `Authorization` header which you have got after successfully logged in.

Your user route is protected by passport so When calling routes that are protected by Passport, your application's API consumers should specify their **access token** as a **Bearer** token in the **Authorization header** of their request.

For example, when using the Guzzle HTTP library you can pass it as below:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/logout', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
    ],
]);
```

from the doc [laravel passport passing access token](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#passing-the-access-token)

Answer (score 0):

When you use Auth::user()->id in your function's body. You have not logged in before.
Please call login api first to get token then set it to the next API call.

Comment: How to call login api? and how to access token?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow a few steps and ensure they are all correct

1. Follow all the setup instruction for Laravel Passport and ensure the backend side is working correctly
2. When making your requests ensure you have passed a correct access token via the authorization header `Authorization: Bearer xxx-token-here-xxx`

Once you have confirmed the above is done correctly ensure your routes are protected by the api guard. If your routes are not protected then passport won't secure them

Below example using a group of routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1',  'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function()
{
    Route::get("articles","ArticleController@read");
    Route::post("articles","ArticleController@create");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this:

```
    $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
```