# Current user's ID in Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have controller method store and defined api route for that method. When I try to store informations from $request everything is ok but current user ID. Auth::user() return null. How to grab that id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [auth()->user() is null in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504046/auth-user-is-null-in-laravel-5-2)

Answer (score 3):

According to @Rahul Reghunath answer in [How to get current user in Laravel API using Passport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417970/how-to-get-current-user-in-laravel-api-using-passport)

you can try using this method to access user id in api middleware:

```
auth('api')->user();
```

an example:

```
Route::get("me",function (){
    $userInfo=auth('api')->user();
    if ($userInfo!==null)
    {
        return "User is logged in. id:".$userInfo->id;
    }else{
        return "User is not logged in.";
    }
});
```

for me it has shown the id when it authenticated with a bearer token:

```
User is logged in. id:6
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make sure that "api user" is logged in to get ID. You can use **auth()->user()->id** or **Auth::user()->id** to get current user id.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying that from custom made auth ( not default auth provided by laravel ), then all your auth required routes should be using `web` middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    // your routes
});
```

Then you can get the Active user id using either

```
Auth::user()->id
```

or

```
auth()->user()->id
```

Comment: I'm trying to access current user in auth:api middleware

Answer (score 0):

Laravel by default provide current user using laravel helper or laravel static method. Examle :
default=>

```php
 \Auth::user();
```

If you used any guard for this then just used

```php
 \Auth::guard('guard_name')->user();
```

If you used api then you can get current user by

```php
auth('api')->user() //it's a laravel helper
```

This one for api route above two for web route